# Using Variable in SaveAs

Tags: excel, vba

I've been creating macros using the old Excel 4 Macro system for years. Unfortunately some of them  don't work now that I've upgraded to 365.
I have 2 issues with saving an invoice
Issue 1, I've saved the master copy into the master Invoices folder using the Invoice number as the filename. I'd like to use a variable `invoiceNumber`, but have only managed to use `ActiveCell`, but at least that works.

```
   Windows("acme - Invoice GB.xltx").Activate
Application.Goto Reference:="Invoice_N"
ChDir "f:\Finance\Invoices"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="F:\Finance\Invoices\" & ActiveCell, FileFormat _
    :=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

Issue 2
I'm trying to save the Invoice as a PDF into the customers Invoices folder, getting the customers name from the invoice

```
 ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="companyname", RefersToR1C1:="=Invoice!R9C1"


ChDir "F:\Clients and Prospects\" & companyname & "\Invoices"

    
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="I" & ActiveCell, Quality:= _
    xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

It does save, but in the root folder, it doesn't pick up the company name.
Any help much appreciated

Comment: A VBA variable is not equivalent to a `Name` in a workbook. `Dim companyname As String`, `companyname = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice").Range("A9").Value`.

Comment: when saving to pdf assign your path to a string variable then use the variable to append in the `Filename:=` line